# FormControl values to database Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am wondering how to store FormControl values to my database. Normally I would just use ngModel but I'm using reactive forms here.

I know how to show the values of the inputs by using this:

```
this.form.value || json
```

But I need to store each input in this:

```
this.user["input1"] = ___
this.user["input2"] = ___
this.user["input3"] = ___
```

Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please check this link.   https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/  . This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
form: FormGroup;
 constructor(){
      this.form= this.fb.group({
          'input1': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'input2': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'input3': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
       }
   }


this.form.controls['input1'].setValue(user.input1);
this.form.controls['input2'].setValue(user.input2);
this.form.controls['input3'].setValue(user.input3);
```

Please read this: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Didn't work for me - probably the placement of your code differs from mine. Mine's like this: this.bookingForm = this._formBuilder.group({

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngModel with reactive forms too.

Create a form group using formbuilder and add a formControlName to each element and formgroup property to form tag.

example.

HTML FILE

```
<form [formGroup]="exampleForm">
 <label for="input1">input1</label>
 <input type="text" formControlName="input1 [(ngModel)]="input1" class="form-control" id="input1">
</form>
```

TS file

```
input1;
exampleForm = this.fb.group({
  input1: [this.input1, [Validators.required]]
})
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
```

and use that input1 to set your value.

```
this.user['input1'] = this.input1
```